# SVG.js - How to access Elements in shadow-root (open) in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, shadow-dom, svg.js

I'm currently working on an [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) Project. In this custom component I want to use [SVG.js 3+](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/).
But since I need to use `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` in my component, I'm facing some issues on inizializing SVG.js.

The standard process to create an SVG and to draw a rect would be like this:

```
this.draw = SVG().addTo("#SVGContainer").viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140);
this.draw.rect(100, 100).move(100, 50).fill('#f06')
```

The problem here is that `.addTo("#SVGContainer")` only can find Elements which are not in the shadow-root. I have tested it with my component which uses shadow-root and with a container which doesn't use shadow-root. As expected SVG.js worked in the Angular Project without Shadow Dom, but didn't work in the Project which uses shadow-root.

I know that with `container.shadowRoot.querySelector(".test").innerHTML` you are able to access shadow elements, but the function `.addTo()` only allowes me to pass the id of my element, so there is no option to pass the dom element itself.

Since `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` is a requirement for my new custom web component I'm wondering if its possible to pass shadow-dom elements to SVG.js or if it just isn't possible at all.

Comment: That addTo function needs to be patched so it can accept a string (as it does now) or an element.. Ask for it on their GitHub Repo, they are quick to respond. https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues

Comment: A different (crazy) idea would be to register a custom window and give it the window object and as document the shadow root. But that's just am idea. Maybe it works :D

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you for your comments. I solved it today. Please consider to read my answer. Cheers

Comment: @fuzzyma Well nice Idea but that would have been my backup backup backup plan if nothing works :D

Comment: A maybe less intrusive method would be to use `SVG.find(selector, shadowroot) ` - that would scope the method to the shadow root and find your element

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Just when I followed the suggestion to create an Issue on their Github, I came across this [Github Issue](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/1012) in which a user says that it is nice that they support even shadow dom and it is nice that you can pass elements directly, but they should document it.

He said that you can pass elements directly. So I had to try one more time and well. It worked.
I created a ViewChild Reference for my Container like this:

```
 @ViewChild('svgContainer') svgContainer: any;
```

and passed it to the `.addTo()` like this:

```
this.draw = SVG().addTo(this.svgContainer.nativeElement).viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140);
```

So there where 2 things why it didnt worked the first time. First I didnt find the documentation (if there is one) where they say you can pass the element itself. And also when I tried it the first time I forgott to add `.nativeElement`.

Comment: About the documentation: if you select 3.1 in the docs (which is not out yet) you will find it. It should be in 3.0 too but It's hard for one person to keep the docs in sync 

Comment: I just noticed that its you from svg.js :D thanks for the info! Good to know it is documented in 3.1.